# Auto expanding divs based on lack of content

Tags: jquery, css, html

I've been working on a template for a database-driven page that ideally should have four divs for content like this:

```
----- -----
| 1 | | 2 |
----- -----
----- -----
| 3 | | 4 |
----- -----
```

The same content will always be in the same boxes. News is in #1, images in #2, etc. Based on the content provided, there could be all of these sections or only one. If for example box 2 doesn't exist, how can I get box 1 to expand to the width of the parent div?

i.e.:

```
-----------
| 1       |
-----------
----- -----
| 3 | | 4 |
----- -----
```

or if 3 & 4 do not exist

```
-----------
| 1       |
-----------
-----------
| 2       |
-----------
```

Granted, this might be something that can only wholly be done with if/then statements, but I was wondering if there was a way to do this in CSS...  Or could it be jquery? I feel like this should be simple but my brain is just not getting how to do it.

I set up two 50% width floating divs side by side, but I'm not sure how it would know how to expand if the other is missing.

Thanks!

Edit: Adding HTML! There's nothing really fancy here yet...

```
    <div class="auth-secondary">

    <div class="auth-upcoming auth-3d">
        <span class="auth-h3">Upcoming Events</span>
        <p>
            <strong>March 5, 2014</strong><br>
            Book signing
        </p>
        <p>
            <strong>March 5, 2014</strong><br>
            Ice cream party
        </p>
    </div><!-- end auth-upcoming -->

    <div class="auth-media auth-3d">
        <span class="auth-h3">Media Gallery</span>
            <p>
                <img src="http://placehold.it/74x74"> &nbsp; 
                <img src="http://placehold.it/74x74"> &nbsp;
                <img src="http://placehold.it/74x74"> &nbsp; 
                <img src="http://placehold.it/74x74"> &nbsp;
            </p>
    </div>
</div> <!-- end auth-secondary-->
```

Comment: can you post an example of your possible html?

Comment: When #2 doesn't exist, does it mean that the `<div>` is empty, or isn't it in the DOM at all? Is it possible to add different classes to the `<div>`'s in the different scenario's?

Comment: @LinkinTED, the div would ideally not be in the DOM at all. Do you mean adding like a "100%" class on #1 if it sees no content in #2?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on your comment that ideally a div wouldn't be in the DOM, here might be something to help you, pure CSS.

Add in your HTML a "wrapping" `div` for each row:

```
<div class="row">
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div>3</div>
    <div>4</div>
</div>
```

Together with this CSS:

```
.row {
    width: 600px;
    display: table;
}
.row > div {
    display: table-cell;
}
```

It will give you this [**result**](http://jsfiddle.net/5sh5R/)

Taking, for example, the second div away, will give you this [**result**](http://jsfiddle.net/5sh5R/1/).

It however makes it harder when div #3 and #4 don't exist and you want div#2 to be on the next line. You'll need to add an extra class or something on the server side of your script.

Hope this will help you!

Comment: Thanks! I like both yours and @Josh-Powell's answers, but for the sake of simplicity, I think this one is the ideal solution for what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an option you can use but it is not pure css sadly, could be depending on what you need.

**How** are the children being added to the parent that contains them?

What I am doing is adding a class `.half` to the child class which will break the child into half the width. To achieve the end result I do need to know the answer to the question I asked.

Here is a demo to play with,

css:

```
body * {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
}

.parent {
    width: 600px;
    height: 300px;
    border: 5px solid #ffdd00;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    padding: 5px;
}

.child {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #ff7200;
}

.child.half {
    width: 49.5%;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

jQuery:

```
var child = '<div class="child">I am a child DIV</div>',
    halfChild = '<div class="child half">I am a child DIV</div>'

$('#fullTwo').on('click', function() {
    if($('.parent').find('.child')) {
        $('.parent').append(halfChild);
        $('.parent').find('.child').addClass('half');
    }
    else {
        $('.parent').append(child);
    }
});
```

Finally, a fiddle: [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/38ha3/2/)

Another fiddle to show how adding another class can effect the layout: [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/TWLCM/1/)

Answer (score 0):

lets say that news, images, comments and advertising classes position your divs this way:

```
-------------------
| news  |  images |
|------------------
| comms |  advert |
-------------------
```

one option whould be that you always have this base Html and based on the content of each div you decide the width of your elements:

```
<div class="news"></div>
<div class="images"></div>
<div class="comments"></div>
<div class="advertising"></div>
```

now your js would look like this:

```
var isNewsEmpty = $('.news').html() == "";
var isImagesEmpty = $('.images').html() == "";
var isCommentsEmpty = $('.comments').html() == "";
var isAdvertisingEmpty = $('.advertising').html() == "";

//now just set width if empty
if (isNewsEmpty) { $('.images').css('width','100%') }
if (isImagesEmpty) { $('.news').css('width','100%') }
if (isCommentsEmpty) { $('.advertising').css('width','100%') }
if (isadvertisingEmpty) { $('.comments').css('width','100%') }
```

hope it helps!

### Update

This would work even is one of the sections does not exits